# Is there a convention about how it is best for humans to take 5-HTP?

Tags: recovery, neurotransmitter, emotional-eating

5-HTP is an amino acid derivative from tryptophan acting as the direct precursor for the neurotransmitter serotonin (5-HT) and hence of melatonin in mammals.
It is found in different foods in insignificant amount but in some particular foods in a significant amount for extraction, as in *Griffonia simplicifolia*.
It is available as a dietary supplement.

Is there a convention about how it is best for humans to take 5-HTP?

<sub>For example, at what time of day, drug interactions to avoid, etc, to increase serotonin levels in an otherwise healthy person, in cases of indication (perhaps emotional eating or recovering from some form of depression).</sub>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

5-HTP is used by physicians a broad usage but recent clinical trials doesn't come up with appropriate *general guidelines* for its dosage, so, no, as of February 2020, there isn't a convention.

### Usage Examples:

- 600 mg
  of 5-HTP was given to the patients and there was significant increase
  in the sleep quality with increase in REM sleep.  While patients
  using smaller doses of 200mg showed lesser degree of improvement in
  sleep quality. For insomnia, the dosage should be between 100-300 mg
  before the bedtime. It can cause nausea in some patients, so
  treatment with 5-HTP, should be started with 50 mg doses. 
  (Via: http://www.altmedrev.com/archive/publications/3/4/271.pdf  )
- Treatment of children with 5- HTP regulates
  the sleep cycle  and this shows improvement in long-term sleep
  terrors (Via:
  https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs00431-004-1444-7).
- 5-HTP is absorbed well when taken orally, approximately 70% enters
  the bloodstream. Therapeutic administration of 5-HTP is used in
  treatment of depression, fibromyalgia and insomnia. (https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/9727088).
- The 5-HTP toxicity is reported at higher concentrations of serotonin
  in the central nervous system. Various cases are reported of heart
  valve damage when taken with serotonin reuptake inhibitors or
  monoamine oxidase inhibitors (
  https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/pharmacology-toxicology-and-pharmaceutical-science/5-hydroxytryptophan).
- Taking more than required amount of 5-HTP is harmful for body. As 5-HTP bypass the feedback loop of serotonin pathway and leads to its accumulation.

### Further reading

This [link](https://www.webmd.com/vitamins-supplements/ingredientreview-794-5-HTP.aspx?drugid=794&drugname=5-HTP) contains user reviews & ratings opinions about the effectiveness of 5-HTP usage in various health issues.

Comment: Some of the sources in this answer are...sketchy at best.

Comment: Hello Twinkle Sheen ; I suggest to change the answer a bit to reflect the notion of a "convention" between "physicians" (can be also clinical dietitians or chiropractics or medical psychologists allowed to prescribe medicine or whatever) about 5-htp ; if the notion is relfect I could upvote and accept the answer ; if you edit the answer, please let me know in the comments that you had done so.

Comment: Yes..it is used by physicians for treating insomnia and anxiety. But till now there is no standard dosage for treating depression.  Check out these links:   
http://pennstatehershey.adam.com/content.aspx?productid=107&pid=33&gid=000283       https://www.webmd.com/vitamins-and-supplements/5-htp-hydroxytryptophan

Comment: @TwinkleSheen I know it is used for insomnia and anxiety ; I don't deny it for a moment ; I also know about an off label from 5-HT insufficiency related obesity usage ; but my question is `convention-focused` hence I personally, humbly, except any answerer to start an answer by saying something like `Yes, this major health organization recommends ...` or by `No, as of February 2020 there is isn't any convention by any organization` and give a source.

Comment: If you follow this comment, which I hope was humble and helpful I can promise you from my 7 years experience in SE that the answer will be better accepted by the community and I will likely "mark it as accepted" myself. In appreciation,

Comment: I hope now my answer makes sense

Comment: Hello @TwinkleSheen I read the answer and suggested an edit. Please follow my suggested edit. I Think it serves the data to the reader in a way that will be more fitting to the question and more well accepted.

Comment: @TwinkleSheen I ask from you again, in humiliation, in the last time - and this is not a threat of any kind of course - in great plea, please review my edit and consider to approve it or rejecting it.

Comment: https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/19836

Comment: @JohnDoea - I reviewed your edit and rejected it. This edit does not make the post even a little bit easier to read, easier to find, more accurate or more accessible. The changes to my mind are damaging as apart from a small formatting tweak, what you did was move the first link to a "further reading" section and did not refer to where in the answer it was talking about. Abbreviating Hydroxytryptophan to HTP is also not helpful whereas Twinkle Sheen helped others by defining what 5-HTP stands for.

Comment: @ChrisRogers my opinion in this context is opposite and I think your comment about HTP is bothersome - a link would explain "What it is".

Comment: @JohnDoea I and another person accepted your edit, but as you can see I re-edited to change the word "exampling." Although that word does exist in dictionaries, that's about the only place it exists. I've never seen it used in the real world and I think most English speakers would be baffled by it.